# Is the hyphen encoded in LDAP DNs?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, antixsslibrary

I am using the AntiXss nuget package v4.3.0 to encode strings used in LDAP connections and queries. I am finding something that I don't understand: if I call

```
Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.LdapDistinguishedNameEncode("test-name")
```

I get the output

```
test#2Dname
```

while everywhere I search (ex [here](https://www.rlmueller.net/CharactersEscaped.htm), [here](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/DN%20Escape%20Values)) or even in the [RFC standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514) (as much as I can understand) it always says that the hyphen is NOT a character to escape.

Is there something I'm not getting or is this a bug of the library?

One of the RDNs in my LDAP tree has a hyphen in it ("CN=John Doe,DC=test-name,DC=net"), so this is a situation I have to handle.

That library doesn't seem to be much mantained nowadays, so it could be a real PITA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a little look through the IL for this package, I can see that it does indeed encode a hyphen character (char 45).

In fact, the following characters between 32 and 126 (inclusive) will all be escaped by `LdapDistinguishedNameEncode`:

```
33 = !
34 = "
38 = &
39 = '
43 = +
44 = ,
45 = -
59 = ;
60 = <
61 = =
62 = >
92 = \
124 = |
```

**Why?**

In the library, a series of characters are declared as 'safe', that do not require escaping.  For some reason, the above characters have been explicitly excluded in `LdapEncoder`:

```
private static IEnumerable DistinguishedNameSafeList()
{
    for (int i = 32; i <= 126; i++)
        if (i != 44 && i != 43 && i != 34 && i != 92 && i != 60 && i != 62 && i != 38 && i != 33 && i != 124 && i != 61 && i != 45 && i != 39 && i != 59)
            yield return (object)i;
}
```

**What to do?**

Presuming you don't want to reimplement the code yourself that's in the library, I'd suggest that you could do a nasty bit of string replacement to correct this:

```
Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.LdapDistinguishedNameEncode("test-name").Replace("#2D", "-");
```

It feels a bit hacky, but if you want to retain the hyphen I don't see what other choice you have sadly.

**RFC 4514**

The RFC explicitly states characters that are escaped, such as:

> - a space (' ' U+0020) or number sign ('#' U+0023) occurring at the beginning of the string;
> - a space (' ' U+0020) character occurring at the end of the string;
> - one of the characters '"', '+', ',', ';', '<', '>',  or '\' (U+0022, U+002B, U+002C, U+003B, U+003C, U+003E, or U+005C,
>     respectively);
> - the null (U+0000) character.

However, it goes on to say:

> Other characters may be escaped.

That somewhat vague statement would indicate that you could potentially expect escaping of any character.

Comment: I had looked into the code too, but I couldn't do the mapping of the various integers inside `DistinguishedNameSafeList()`. But then to be sure to cover all cases, shouldn't I replace all the other "wrongly" escaped characters like "!" ?

Comment: @Piddu That may be your only option if you want to convert these back to their unescaped equivalents. It would all depend on your usage of the resulting output

Comment: I think you're better off writing your own method to escape what you need to escape.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I'd personally also go with that approach, given that you can guarantee the output matches your expectation.

Comment: Maybe too late, but there is an option to use activeds com library and adspathname interface. It was designed to perform escaping/unescaping operations with DN’s. It’s a little bit tricky to use, but works great in my c# and c++ projects